# Get the rows that not exist in the table A

Tags: mysql

This query returns the students ID of all the students that belong to the schedule ID 6004.

```
SELECT studentID
FROM 
    (SELECT studentID
     FROM schedule_students
     WHERE scheduleID = '6004') AS A
```

This query returns the student IDs who attend the schedule 6004

```
SELECT studentID
FROM 
    (SELECT studentID
     FROM attendance
     WHERE scheduleID = '6004'
       AND status = 1) AS B
```

I would like somehow put those queries together and subtract B from A to get the student IDs that didn't attend the schedule 6004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start your query can be simplify to:

```
SELECT studentID
FROM schedule_students
WHERE scheduleID = '6004'

SELECT studentID
FROM attendance
WHERE scheduleID = '6004'
  AND status = 1
```

Now the the easy way is use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT ss.studentID
FROM schedule_students ss
LEFT JOIN attendance a 
  ON ss.scheduleID  = a.scheduleID 
 AND ss.studentID = a.studentID
 AND a.status = 1
WHERE ss.sheduleID = '6004'
  AND a.studentID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT studentID 
FROM (SELECT studentID 
      FROM schedule_students 
      WHERE scheduleID = '6004') 
WHERE studentID NOT IN (SELECT studentID
                        FROM (SELECT studentID
                              FROM attendance
                              WHERE scheduleID = '6004'
                                AND status = 1))
```

It seems a bit complicated, but you need to check which aren't (NOT IN) the other query. :)